# Disable buttons if textfield is empty on custom dialog

Tags: android

Hi I have a custom dialog when new_post_message is clicked I want it to check it there is anything in edittext before and if nothing is entered to disable the button any help would be great.  Thanks!

```
post_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    items.add(new MessageItem(55, new_message_to.getText().toString(), "image", DateTime.now(), new_message_text.getText().toString()));

                    itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    if (v.getId() == R.id.button_post);
                    new_message_to.setText("");
                    new_message_text.setText("");

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher()

                {@Override
                 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

                        new_message_to.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
                        new_message_text.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                        String s1 = new_message_to.getText().toString();
                        String s2 = new_message_text.getText().toString();


                        if (s1.equals("") || s2.equals("")) {
                            post_button.setEnabled(false);
                        } else {
                            post_button.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                    }
                };

            });
```

Comment: Nope if i leave both edittext fields blank it doesn't disable the button

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
if (new_message_text.equals("")|| new_message_to.equals("")) {
    ....
}
```

new_message_text is never equals to `""` because `""` is an EditText (a *view* for entering text) and not a String. You have to compare it to the text actually entered.

So you should do a:

```
if (new_message_text.getText().toString().equals("")|| new_message_to.getText().toString().equals("")) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `textWatcher` to editText `new_message_to` and `new_message_text` as

```
 new_message_to.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
 new_message_text.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

and use TextWatcher method as

```
    private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {@Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                String s1 = new_message_to.getText().toString();
                String s2 = new_message_text.getText().toString();

                if (s1.equals("") || s2.equals("")) {
                    post_button.setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    post_button.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
    };
```

and remove

```
 if (v.getId() == R.id.button_post);
                        new_message_to.setText("");
                        new_message_text.setText("");
```

from onClick method.

**Edit**
use `textWatcher` method in your activity class and remove from `post_button.setOnClickListener` and use

```
new_message_to.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
 new_message_text.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

in `OnCreate` method in last.

Comment: where should I put the  new_message_to.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

Comment: @sim use `textWatcher` method in your activity class  and remove from `post_button.setOnClickListener`